# Image's height increases when inside flex container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexbox

When I change the style of `div.container` to `display: flex`, the images height increases. How do I stop this from happening?

Before:

```js
$('.text').prev('img').css('height',$('.text').outerHeight());
```

```css
div.container {
  border: 1px solid;
}
img {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMzg2Mjg1OTk0NF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMjQ4MTA3Mw@@._V1_SX300.jpg" alt="RED" />
  <div class="text">
    <h2>Red</h2>
    <p>When his peaceful life is threatened by a high-tech assassin, .</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

After:

```js
$('.text').prev('img').css('height',$('.text').outerHeight());
```

```css
div.container {
  border: 1px solid;
  display: flex;
}
img {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMzg2Mjg1OTk0NF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMjQ4MTA3Mw@@._V1_SX300.jpg" alt="RED" />
  <div class="text">
    <h2>Red</h2>
    <p>When his peaceful life is threatened by a high-tech assassin, .</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `display: flex` element will have the style `align-items: stretch` by default. You can change that to `align-items: flex-start` to avoid your child elements matching the height of their tallest sibling.

Comment: Happy to help 